# Add placeholder into contact form 7 recaptcha text field

Tags: plugin-development

I want to add "Placeholder" into contact form 7 really-simple-recaptcha plugin text field. I tried `$('field_id).attr("Placeholder" "My Placeholder Text")` using jQuery. Is there another method to do it?

Comment: Besides [Howdy_McGee](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/7355/howdy-mcgee)  answer, note that there's a  missing comma between `"Placeholder" "My Placeholder Text"`

Answer (score 0):

The Really Simple Captcha box is exactly like a normal WPCF7 textbox and a plceholder can be added in the same way:

```
[captchac my-captcha id:my-capcha-img]
[captchar my-captcha id:my-captcha-input Placeholder "* Captcha"]
```